# Using a Pi B with a 40pin GPIO paddleboard?

Tags: gpio, rpi.gpio

I posted a question a while back about interfacing GPIO pins directly into a breadboard. Someone replied

> use a paddleboard/cobblerboard!

and so I did. I bought [this](https://shop.cyntech.co.uk/collections/raspberry-pi/products/40-way-raspberry-pi-b-paddle-board?variant=842731537) paddleboard.
  But...

It's 40-pin and I have a pi B.

Is there any way to cut extra pins off..etc or do I have to return it ?
SOOOOOOOO grateful for a good reply.

Comment: I think you could just try plug in the 40-pin connector on the 26-pin connector. The first 26-pin of the B+ is same as the B. It should just work.

Answer (score 1):

You could probably use this [cable](https://www.adafruit.com/products/1986) (in reverse). The extra 14 pins on the cobbler wont work but it will breakout the first 26 pins. alternatively, you could buy this [cobbler model](https://www.adafruit.com/products/1754)  which is designed for the 26 pin Pi's

Comment: Looking at that "paddleboard" it appears the cable can be detached and potentially reversed, which would mean you should (might?) be able to arrange it with the other end protruding north of the pi and still have the correct connections in the right place.   *Just think carefully about how, and double check by using a volt/multimeter on the two 5V pins.*  If they don't both read 5V, you did it wrong.  As long as you don't connect anything to the paddleboard, this should be a safe experiment.

Comment: Or put in an envelope and I'll mail you a 26 pin cable in exchange ;D

Comment: @goldilocks I almost said the same thing the problem with a straight 26 pin cable is you would need to remove the center lug which maintains the polarity and proper connections. Just look at the number of questions we get because they reverse the cable.

Comment: @goldilocks I live in the UK so I can't really post stuff. To. AMERICA!

Comment: I'm not in America.  Just north of there.  Part of the Commonwealth brother! (sister?)  Steve is the Yank.

Comment: I've fixed the issues ect but does my paddleboard have a resistor/fuse/piprotection inside it, or do I have to buy one ?

Comment: @goldilocks I'm a brother. =D

Comment: @goldilocks* A sixth grade brother.....

Comment: @FractalFreak99 this is not the way to handle additional questions. (as a string of comments) if you have another question please click the ask question button above.

Comment: @SteveRobillard this isn't a question as of such.. I mean it still applies to the USE OF A PADDLEBOARD so yeah.. And I can just buy the component at MAPLINS so it's not something that **needs** to be answered.